# Chrome Web Store give away

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store

Can you give a Chrome Web Store App (that you own) to a friend at no cost even if the app is a payed app?

If so how?

i currently have a Chrome packaged app, and i want to give it away to some friends at no cost.